# Share URL on Twitter: HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: php, html, ssl, twitter

I'm allowing my website's visitors to share a URL on Twitter using this code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My page title&url=<?php echo $url; ?>&via=twitter_username">Share on Twitter</a>
```

If the visitor is logged-in, the URL of the page will be `https://example.com` and if they are logged-out it will be `http://example.com`. Should I use HTTP or HTTPS for the share URL (i.e. the value of `$url`)? Grateful if you could explain why I should be using either one in your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have ssl configured for your site?

Comment: Yes I do have it configured.

Comment: then I don't see any reason why the share URL shouldn't be the https link

Comment: i need to make the choice because I don't want the share count for that page to be divided into two. I suppose my question should be is it better practice to share HTTPS links or HTTP links? And which should I choose to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is at Twitter **does** differentiate counts between `http` and `https` URLs.

You can use the link counter API (does *not* require authentication) to check

```
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=
```

For example there are different counts between these two URLs:

```
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://vine.co/v/MdEvQiw2nFm
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=https://vine.co/v/MdEvQiw2nFm
```

In your case, people can view your site over both `http` **and** `https`.  Here's what I think you should do....

- Make your entire site `https` only.  That will keep things nice and simple.
- If that's not possible - only share the `https` link.  Assuming that a non-logged in user will still be able to see it.
- If non-logged-in users *cannot* see `https` content - only share unencrypted `http` links.

Comment: Thanks - agreed I should make everything run HTTPS. I'll make that change. Is there any benefit of choosing to share `https` over `http` or vice versa?

Comment: People may be more inclined to trust an `https` link. Other than that, there's little benefit.